# aws step function converting special characters to UTF-8 in URL (not able to pass correct URL with query parameter to API gateway)

Tags: url, aws-api-gateway, query-string, aws-step-functions

I am using api-gateway invoke task in step-function but not able to use query parameters in PATH

here is my step function defination

```
{
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::apigateway:invoke",
  "Parameters": {
    "ApiEndpoint": "endpoint",
    "AuthType": "IAM_ROLE",
    "Headers": {
      "Content-Type": [
        "application/json"
      ]
    },
    "Method": "GET",
    "Path": "path?a=1",
    "RequestBody.$": "$"
  },
  "End": true
}
```

when I use a=1 in query parameter it converts it to `path%3F%7B%7D` like format and give error.

I also know about queryparameter in apigateway invoke task but the problem is I have input like a=1 if I pass this to query parameter it will also fail. as query paramter expect something like this

```
 "QueryParameters": {
      "a": [
        "1"
      ]
    }
```

Any idea how to solve this problem within step function?

Comment: Sounds like you already know the answer in terms of using the `QueryParameters`!? Currently the ?a=1 is contact and there is no reason to not use QueryParameters. Is that data actually variable? If so: can you change the structure of the data? Worst case you need to write a lambda to do the transformation.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 for your input, no it's not variable.. this data actually coming from api-gateway as query parameter and it is dynamic. I am hesitant to use lambda.. trying to find a way if we can do this in step function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved problem by passing query parameter from api-gateway separately as key and value

```
{
    "key": "a",
    "value": "1"
}
```

then used Intrinsic functions in state machine to handle in QueryParameter like this:

```
"QueryParameters.$": "States.StringToJson(States.Format(' \\{  \"{}\":[\"{}\"]  \\}', $.key , $.value))"
```